# Back event/button with load() function with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I created PhoneGap app which use load() function to load a new page in the app.

The detection of BackButton event isn't valid for iOS and Windows.

What I want to know is how to remember the last page called in order to return it with the event BackButton.

**What I have to do to enable back event with the back button ?**

Comment: Check this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-load-content-with-back-button-enable-and-refresh-using-ajax

Answer (score 1):

The event fires when the user presses the back button. To override the default back-button behavior, register an event listener for the `backbutton` event. It is no longer necessary to call any other method to override the back-button behavior.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
    alert("Back button pressed");
}
```

have a look at more options

[cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I ever known how to detect when back event fires. 
Especially since the detection of this event is not valid for iOS and Windows.

What I want to know is how to remember the last page called in order to return it with the event BackButton

Answer (score 0):

How about just remember the last page you visited in *localStorage* or *sessionStorage*?
Then redirect to that page when <kbd>Back</kbd> button pressed.
I did it and it works well.